# Two Runnables on the same thread ending at the same time. Is conflict possible?

Tags: java, android, callback, runnable

Below is a simplification of some code I have for a custom `View`. It has a `Runnable` for an animation, and a `Runnable` for audio. The `start()` function starts both the animation runnable and the audio runnable. Each runnable implements an inteface with a callback on completion.

I need to know when both are finished, so I can call `onBothRunnablesFinished()`.

```
public class Foo extends View {
  RunnableA mRunnableA;
  RunnableB mRunnableB;

  // overrides of onCreate, onMeasure, onDraw, etc...

  private void onBothRunnablesFinished() {
    // Do stuff when both runnables are finished...
  }

  public void start() {
    mRunnableA = new RunnableA();
    mRunnableB = new RunnableB();
    post(mRunnableA);
    post(mRunnableB);
  }

  private class RunnableA implements Runnable, AnimationListener {
    private MyAnimation mAnim;
    private boolean mRunning = false;

    public RunnableA() {
      mAnim = new MyAnimation();
      mAnim.setAnimationListener(this);
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
      return mRunning;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      mRunning = true;
      startAnimation(mAnim);
    }

    // Called when mAnim finishes
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
      mRunning = false;
      // **WHAT IF THE OTHER RUNNABLE FINISHES NOW?**
      if (mRunnableB.isRunning() == false) {
        onBothRunnablesFinished();
      }
    }
  }

  private class RunnableB implements Runnable, OnCompletionListener {
    private MyMediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    private boolean mRunning = false;

    public RunnableB() {
      mMediaPlayer = MyMediaPlayer();
      mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
      return mRunning;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      mRunning = true;
      mMediaPlayer.start();
    }

    // Called when mMediaPlayer finishes
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
      mRunning == false;
      // **WHAT IF THE OTHER RUNNABLE FINISHES NOW?**
      if (mRunnableA.isRunning() == false) {
        onBothRunnablesFinished();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've labeled a couple areas of interest with comments. What would happen if the audio and animation runnables finish at the same time? More specifically, could the callback of one runnable interrupt the callback of the other in the commented locations above? Is this possible??

I hope not, because then `onBothRunnablesFinished` would be called twice. If this is the case, how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've deleted my other answer. Now that I think about it you don't even need Runnables since the animation and media player frameworks will use their own threads. However you still need to synchronize the call to `onActivityFinished()` (formerly called onBothRunnablesFinished()) since the framework threads may finish simultaneously:

```
public class Foo extends View implements AnimationListener, OnCompletionListener {
    private MyAnimation mAnim;
    private MyMediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    private boolean mIsOneActivityFinished = false;

    synchronized private void onActivityFinished() {
        if(!mIsOneActivityFinished) {
             // The first activity is finished. Set the flag and return.
             mIsOneActivityFinished = true;
             return;
        }

        // Do stuff when both activities are finished...
    }

    public void start() {
        mAnim = new MyAnimation();
        mAnim.setAnimationListener(this);
        startAnimation(mAnim);

        mMediaPlayer = MyMediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    }


    // Called when mAnim finishes
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        onActivityFinished();
    }


    // Called when mMediaPlayer finishes
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        onActivityFinished();
    }
}
```

Trust me this code will work and is way cleaner. Don't even give a thought to using Runnables as Android does the multi-threading for you.

Barry

Comment: I like this better than my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. This makes sense, and works well. The quality of answers I can get on SO never ceases to amaze me.

Answer (score 1):

you can use an AtomicInteger initialized to 2

and finish the run with

```
if(atomicInt.decrementAndGet()==0)onBothRunnablesFinished();
```

Comment: I'm glad you said this. I was thinking of doing something similar, but had never used atomic primitives before, so I was hesitant.

Comment: However, I do have a question. According to the android docs, both of these `Runnables` are executed on the same thread. Are atomic primitives or synchronized functions still effective under these circumstances?

Comment: This has the detraction of making the coordination semantics much more nebulous.

Comment: We are debating  how to synchronize the Runnables and missing the big picture. It is not necessary to use a Runnable to start either activity since their frameworks will use their own threads. Therefore Foo can act as the listener for both activities and need only synchronize the call to onBothRunnablesFinished().

Answer (score 1):

I would inject a POJO mutex object into both the runnable objects and use it to synchronize both the `isRunning` and `onCompletion` methods.  Acutally, `isRunning` does not need synchronization since it's only called from within the syncrhonized code in `onCompletion`, but I would consider the synchronization semantics much clearer with it also synchronized.

Using RunnableA as a template (make the changes marked `// completion` to both classes):

```
private class RunnableA implements Runnable, AnimationListener {
  private MyAnimation mAnim;
  private boolean mRunning = false;
  private Object  mExecutionMutex; // completion

  public RunnableA(Object mtx) { // completion
    mAnim = new MyAnimation();
    mAnim.setAnimationListener(this);
    mExecutionMutex=mtx;
  }

  public boolean isRunning() {
    synchronized(mExecutionMutex) { // completion (Note: This is actually unnecessary)
      return mRunning;
      }
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    mRunning = true;
    startAnimation(mAnim);
  }

  // Called when mAnim finishes
  @Override
  public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    synchronized(mExecutionMutex) { // completion
      mRunning = false;
      if(mRunnableB.isRunning() == false) {
        onBothRunnablesFinished();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What would I pass the constructor? A new `Object`? The `View`'s `this`? Also, why would we not create just one mutex object for the `View`? What advantage is there in creating a mutex for each `Runnable`?

Comment: A plain Object as long as it's exactly the same instance to both runnables.  I would not use the View instance because it would be (IMO) very bad practice to use an object as a mutex for state unrelated to *it's* operation.

Comment: And yes, you can have the mutex as a member of view and use it from both runnables - I am just used to using *static* inner classes and passing parameters; our standard actively discourage using inner classes because of the ease with which you can accidentally mess with the containing class's state.

Comment: Runnables are unnecessary since onAnimationEnd() and onCompletion() will be called by threads owned by their respective frameworks.

Comment: Thanks to both Software Monkey and Barry Fruitman. This discussion has helped me better understand Java Threads, the Android API, and my own code.